# How to edit Parse server code to use Amazon S3 for saving files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, parse-platform, amazon-s3

This is a n00b question. I am using Parse server for an application hosted on Heroku and with the back-end of MongoLab.

I want to use Amazon S3 to save files in back-end while using Parse server SDK in my application.

I referred this and followed the steps to create bucket in Amazon S3
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Storing-Files-in-AWS-S3

The link says that I should edit the Parse server code to point to the Amazon S3 bucket, my question is how can I do this? Do I pull a copy of my Parser server on Heroku and edit it on my local system or I go to Heroku and edit the Parse server?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would choose git for versioning the Parse Server.

What I've did with my deployment of Parse Server (mostly I've used this tutorial http://rogerstringer.com/2016/02/04/parse-server-heroku/).

1. clone the Parse Server on my github account
2. I've did a new project on Heroku
3. link Heroku with my github project (under Parse Server project -> Deploy)

[image: I have this on my Heroku -> Deploy tab]

4. anytime a modification was necessary on Heroku side, I've pull down the git project, I will add the modification, do the commit to git project. From Heroku side I would do a manual deploy.

[image: Manual deploy of Heroku]

The most modifications I've applied were to `index.js` from Parse Server.

```
var api = new ParseServer({
    databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
    cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
    appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'reciparia',
    masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || '', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
    clientKey: process.env.CLIENT_KEY || 'holla'
});
```

On Heroku side, you can have some environment variables, that maybe you need to modify or add. So, what I've understood, is that you can have variables defined on the interface of Heroku, or just add them in code.

[image: Variables]

Comment: Are there any advantages of updating Parser server by modifications to your git, instead of making changes using heroku toolbelt?
$ heroku login
Clone the repository
Use Git to clone APP NAME'S source code to your local machine.
$ heroku git:clone -a superorigami
$ cd APPNAME

Comment: If Parse Server is updating, at deployment your modifications will be overritten and you have to do them again. Using git, at least you could do a merge. Git has advantages over simple file modification: https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/ebook/command-line/basics/why-use-version-control

Answer (score 0):

I edited using Heroku toolbelt